# scrapy python CrawlSpider not crawling

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy.spiders.crawl import CrawlSpider, Rule 
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor 

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'genericSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [url_1, url_2, url_3]

    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(),                     
            callback='parse',   
            follow=True        
        ),
    ]

    def parse(self, response): 
        hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
        links = hxs.xpath('*//a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            print(link)
        print()
```

I'm attempting to crawl a website. For an example of my code, I'm just extracting all links and printing them out to the terminal.

This process works great for the urls in the start_urls, but it doesn't seem that the spider will crawl the extracted urls.

This is the point of the CrawlSpider, correct? visit a page, collect its links and visit all those links until it runs out of them?

I've been stuck for a few days, any help would be great.

Comment: `yield Request(link)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you name your method `parse`. As per the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule), this name should be avoided in case of using `CrawlSpider` as it leads to problems. Just rename the method to e.g. `parse_link` (and adjust the `callback` argument in `Rule`) and it will work.

Also, remember that `allowed_domains` attribute must match with URLs you intend to crawl.